# Building a native Joomla 3.1 component with refereing com_weblinks component

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I'm going to develop joomla 3.1 component.

I have checked [lend](http://lendr.websparkinc.com) tutorial. And some people ask us to go through com_weblinks component which is fully written in new MVC style.

Can you please explain img and alt attribute in menu tag and its contents submenu section in weblinks.xml.

And also can you explain link in com_weblinks_categories (option=com_categories&extension=com_weblinks)? How it work? What is the purpose of extension parameter?

```
<submenu>
        <!--
            Note that all & must be escaped to &amp; for the file to be valid
            XML and be parsed by the installer
        -->
        <menu link="option=com_weblinks" view="links" img="class:weblinks"
            alt="Weblinks/Links">com_weblinks_links</menu>
        <menu link="option=com_categories&amp;extension=com_weblinks"
            view="categories" img="class:weblinks-cat" alt="Weblinks/Categories">com_weblinks_categories</menu>
    </submenu>
```

And also anyone explain this check condition and parameters and its pattern in controller.php

```
$this->checkEditId('com_weblinks.edit.weblink', $id)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to articles, banners, weblinks, newsfeed, contacts etc, they use categories. The categories component is not only used for articles but all of the mentioned above. So when you go to view the weblinks, the URL will be `option=com_weblinks` however when viewing the category, it will use the parent component that's used for it `option=com_categories`. The child extension is then defined after like so:

```
option=com_categories&amp;extension=com_weblink
```

As for the `checkEditID` function, have a look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJController%3a%3acheckEditId). It's basically a method to check whether or not the ID is in the edit list.

If you look on the Joomla 2.5 menu, you will see small icons on the left hand side of each menu item which I believe `img="class:weblinks-cat"` is supposed to be used for, however they don't show on Joomla 3.1. I'm not sure why but can always find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Weblinks is most definitely not written in the newest mvc style used by Lendr, if you are coming from 1.5 it is written in the style you should use for 2.5. That style (now known as legacy) also works in J3, but if you extend the base classes you need to rename them.